# Is SonarQube 4.0 compatible with java 8

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.0

I have projects using Java 8 and i'm using sonarQube 4.0, i need to know if that work without any issue, i searched on official Sonar site and i didn't find anything, can anyone help me?

Comment: yes i tried with java 8 and SonarQube 4.0 with plugin Java 1.4 and i had the following errors : [ERROR] org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unsupported Java version for PMD: 1.8                                         [ERROR] [02:15:20.280] Unable to process bytecode of class 'xxx'
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project xxx: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unsupported Java version for PMD: 1.8 -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1):

A plugin to support JAVA 8 was released at the end of march 2014 . So you should be able to work with it .

Comment: yes thanks for you response, i had seen that but i need to know if is that release of plugin compatible with sonarQube 4.0 ???? that's my question

Comment: Yes , it is compatible .

Comment: therefore have you any idea of what is versions of  java plugin  and findbug of sonar can i use to make that possible

Comment: Version 2.4.0  will do

Comment: did you check that version 2.4.0 of java plugin is compatible with sonar 4.0 ? because checked that this version 2.4.0 are available only for sonar 4.2 and newest version by against i checked there is a version 2.0 of this plugin i need to know if it's compatible with sonar 4.0 and java 8